# Limitations of Windows containers for localhost and published ports

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I've read the section [*"Limitations of Windows containers for localhost and published ports"*](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#windows-containers-and-windows-server-2016%22) from docs.docker.com and understood that **I need to use the container IP to be able to access to port80** of my container on DockerForWindows.

Howerwise I'm not able to browse the container IP using http://172.14.0.2 or even ping from my Windows host.

*docker file* = https://github.com/cjonesdev/docker-amazonlinux-lamp/blob/master/Dockerfile

*docker run* = `docker run -ti --name lamp -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 3306:3306 -v D:\Dropbox\www:/var/www/html -d amazonlinux6`

*docker ps result* = `989094308f8c    amazonlinux    "/bin/bash"  0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp lamp`

From the docs.docker.com I guess that it's implicite that the Windows Host should be able to nat the container IP by default, unfortunately in my case it's not.

Following a similar conversation : https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221 it's look like in some case a Windows route need to be added in order to communicate properly with the DockerNat and the containerIP.

I've tried the following route add without success :

`route /P add 172.17.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.0.75.1` (IP dockerNat)

`route /P add 172.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.0.13` (IP windowsHost)

Does anyone already facing a similar situation? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are using Docker toolbox or docker for windows?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I'm using docker for windows.

Comment: try `ipconfig` and there will be a `192.168.X.X` IP for docker, try using that IP to reach the container and see if it works?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for the response but as described the `docker ip` is `10.0.75.1` and `container ip` is `172.17.0.2` and both cannot be browse.

Comment: Does you machine have the Hyper-V software installed? If not then install it and check the VM network settings in HyperV

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes Hyper-V was installed. I checked Hyper-V manager and I see that DockerNat is set to `Internal Network`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've changed the settings into external network, and now I'm getting an `HTTP ERROR 404` when browsing the ip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153320/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-alexandre-roux).

Comment: Looking at your post, it seems to me that you are not actually using Windows Containers? I think perhaps you are using Docker for Windows in Linux Containers Mode (the default). If this is the case, then the localhost restriction that you linked at the top of your post does not apply, that only relates to Windows Server containers.